# How to draw like this picture with tikz

Tags: tikz-styles

Can some one helpe me to draw this picture with tikz?.

[image]

code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=10]
%
\coordinate (C1) at (0.3,-0.15);
\coordinate (C2) at (0.55,-0.15);
\coordinate (C3) at (0.425,-0.025);
\coordinate (C4) at (0.425,-0.275);
%
\coordinate (D1) at (0.85,-0.05);
\coordinate (D2) at (0.9,0.05);
\coordinate (D3) at (0.875,0.125);
\coordinate (D4) at (0.875,-0.125);
%
\coordinate (E1) at (0.375,0.375);
\coordinate (E2) at (0.625,0.375);
\coordinate (E3) at (0.525,0.425);
\coordinate (E4) at (0.525,0.325);
%
\coordinate (F1) at (0.15,0.015);
\coordinate (F2) at (0.1,-0.015);
\coordinate (F3) at (0.125,0.125);
\coordinate (F4) at (0.125,-0.125);
%
\coordinate (G1) at (0.375,-0.375);
\coordinate (G2) at (0.625,-0.375);
\coordinate (G3) at (0.475,-0.425);
\coordinate (G4) at (0.575,-0.325);

\begin{scope}[thick,dashed]
\draw (C1) -- (C4) -- (C2) -- (C3) -- (C1);
\draw (D1) -- (D4) -- (D2) -- (D3) -- (D1);
\draw (E1) -- (E4) -- (E2) -- (E3) -- (E1);
\draw (F1) -- (F4) -- (F2) -- (F3) -- (F1);
\draw (G1) -- (G4) -- (G2) -- (G3) -- (G1);
\end{scope}
\draw (F3) -- (F2) -- (C1) -- (C3) -- (E4) -- (E1);
\draw (C1) -- (C4) -- (G3) -- (G1) -- (F4) -- (F2);
\draw (D1) -- (C2) -- (C3) -- (E4) -- (E2) -- (D3) -- (D1);
\draw (D1) -- (C2) -- (C4) -- (G3) -- (G2) --(D4) -- (D1);
\draw (E2) -- (E3) -- (E1) -- (F3) -- (F2) -- (F4) -- (G1) -- (G3) --  (G2) -- (D4) -- (D1) -- (D3) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should 1) use the points as 3d points, i.e. with three coordinates; 2) draw a regular octahedron first; 3) cut it with 6 planes to obtain your figure, and compute the points of intersection with the planes.

Comment: i dont know how work in 3D.

Comment: A place where to start is the manual http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf, page 559.

Answer (score 3):

As always with TikZ and 3d: Construct your graphics from the back to the front. (Or use layers but that still needs organizing.)

1. the back-sides of the cube
2. the back-edges of the cube
3. the diamonds in the background
4. the hexagons inside the cube but on the back
5. the axes inside the cube
6. the hexagons inside the cube but on the front
7. the diamonds in the front
8. the front-sides of the cube
9. the axes outside the cube

I chose not to fill the front-sides of the cube because that would have just murkied the whole picture.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x=(-120:1cm*sin 30), y=(0:1cm), z=(90:1cm),
  %
  % h: half the height of the cube
  % r: half the diagonal of the square sides that touch the cube
  declare function={h=2; r=1;},
  %
  bg/.style={densely dotted},
  fg/.style={solid},
  axis bg/.style={densely dashed},
  axis fg/.style={solid,-{Stealth[round,/tikz/fill opacity=1]}},
  %
  square fill/.style={fill=blue!50},
  hex fill/.style   ={fill=green!50},
  cube fill/.style  ={fill=red!50},
  % 
%   debug/.style={shape=rectangle,font=\tiny,text=gray,inner sep=0pt, fill=white},
  %
  fill opacity=.5,
  %
  insert dia/.style={
    insert path={(#1n) -- (#1e) -- (#1s) -- (#1w) -- cycle}},
]

% corners of the cube
\foreach \side/\sign in {back/-, front/+}
\coordinate (\side-nw) at (\sign h, -h,  h)
 coordinate (\side-ne) at (\sign h,  h,  h)
 coordinate (\side-se) at (\sign h,  h, -h)
 coordinate (\side-sw) at (\sign h, -h, -h);

% corners of the squares/diamonds that touch the cube
\foreach \sign in {+,-}
  \foreach \x/\y/\z in {x/y/z, y/x/z, z/y/x}
    \coordinate[label={[shape=coordinate,debug/.try]:{\x\sign n}}]
       (\x\sign n) at (xyz cs: \x=\sign h, \y= 0, \z= r)
     coordinate[label={[shape=coordinate,debug/.try]:{\x\sign e}}]
       (\x\sign e) at (xyz cs: \x=\sign h, \y= r, \z= 0)
     coordinate[label={[shape=coordinate,debug/.try]:{\x\sign s}}]
       (\x\sign s) at (xyz cs: \x=\sign h, \y= 0, \z=-r)
     coordinate[label={[shape=coordinate,debug/.try]:{\x\sign w}}]
       (\x\sign w) at (xyz cs: \x=\sign h, \y=-r, \z= 0)
     coordinate[label={[shape=coordinate,debug/.try]:{\x\sign m}}]
       (\x\sign m) at (xyz cs: \x=\sign h, \y= 0, \z= 0);

% 1: fill the cube's sides in the bg
\path[cube fill, bg]            (back-nw) rectangle (back-se)  [insert dia=x-]
  {[canvas is xz plane at y=-h] (back-nw) rectangle (front-sw) [insert dia=y-]}
  {[canvas is xy plane at z=-h] (back-sw) rectangle (front-se) [insert dia=z-]};

% 2: draw the lines of the cube in the bg
\draw[bg] (back-sw) -- (back-nw)
          (back-sw) -- (back-se)
          (back-sw) -- (front-sw);

% 3: fill the diamonds in the bg (no draw because this will done by the hexagons)
\foreach \x in {x,y,z}
  \path[square fill, bg] [insert dia=\x-];

% 4: draw and fill the hexagons in the bg
\draw[hex fill, bg] (x-n) -- (z+s) -- (z+w) -- (y-n) -- (y-w) -- (x-w) -- cycle
                    (x-s) -- (z-s) -- (z-w) -- (y-s) -- (y-w) -- (x-w) -- cycle
                    (z+s) -- (z+e) -- (y+n) -- (y+w) -- (x-e) -- (x-n) -- cycle
                    (x-e) -- (x-s) -- (z-s) -- (z-e) -- (y+s) -- (y+w) -- cycle;

% 5: axes inside the cube
\foreach \x/\y/\z in {x/y/z, y/x/z, z/x/y}
  \draw[axis bg] (0,0,0) -- (xyz cs: \x=h, \y=0, \z=0);

% 6: hexagons in the fg
\draw[hex fill, fg] (x+n) -- (z+n) -- (z+w) -- (y-n) -- (y-e) -- (x+w) -- cycle
                    (y-e) -- (y-s) -- (z-w) -- (z-n) -- (x+s) -- (x+w) -- cycle
                    (z+e) -- (y+n) -- (y+e) -- (x+e) -- (x+n) -- (z+n) -- cycle
                    (y+s) -- (z-e) -- (z-n) -- (x+s) -- (x+e) -- (y+e) -- cycle;

% 7: diamonds in the fg
\foreach \x in {x,y,z}
  \draw[square fill, fg] [insert dia=\x+];

\draw[fg]                     (front-nw) rectangle (front-se) [insert dia=x+]
 {[canvas is xz plane at y=h] (front-ne) rectangle (back-se)  [insert dia=y+]}
 {[canvas is xy plane at z=h] (back-nw)  rectangle (front-ne) [insert dia=z+]};

% 9: the axes outside of the cube
\foreach \x/\y/\z in {x/y/z, y/x/z, z/x/y}
  \draw[axis fg] (xyz cs: \x=h, \y=0, \z=0) -- (xyz cs: \x=h + 1.5, \y=0, \z=0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]